# Node.Js doesn't execute anonymous functions?? -aws lambda -alexa skill

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, httprequest, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently working on a Alexa Skill for my Smart Home.
I created a Lambda function and want to make a http request to a server. but it wont execute any of my anon. functions.

A lambda code example:

```
/* This code has been generated from your interaction model by skillinator.io

/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint quote-props: ["error", "consistent"]*/

// There are three sections, Text Strings, Skill Code, and Helper Function(s).
// You can copy and paste the contents as the code for a new Lambda function, using the alexa-skill-kit-sdk-factskill template.
// This code includes helper functions for compatibility with versions of the SDK prior to 1.0.9, which includes the dialog directives.



 // 1. Text strings =====================================================================================================
 //    Modify these strings and messages to change the behavior of your Lambda function

const request = require("request");
let speechOutput;
let reprompt;
let welcomeOutput = "Hallo xyz!";
let welcomeReprompt = "xy";
// 2. Skill Code =======================================================================================================
"use strict";
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const APP_ID = "my id";  // TODO replace with your app ID (OPTIONAL).
speechOutput = '';
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit(':ask', welcomeOutput, welcomeReprompt);
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.HelpIntent.';
        reprompt = '';
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, reprompt);
    },
   'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.CancelIntent';
        this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
    },
   'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        speechOutput = 'Placeholder response for AMAZON.StopIntent.';
        this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
   },
   'SessionEndedRequest': function () {
        speechOutput = '';
        //this.emit(':saveState', true);//uncomment to save attributes to db on session end
        this.emit(':tell', speechOutput);
   },
    'LichtIntent': function () {
        //delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slot values
       let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);
        speechOutput = '';
        //any intent slot variables are listed here for convenience

        let zimmerSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.zimmer.value;
        console.log(zimmerSlotRaw);
        let zimmerSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.zimmer);
        console.log(zimmerSlot);
        let was_lichtSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.was_licht.value;
        console.log(was_lichtSlotRaw);
        let was_lichtSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.was_licht);
        console.log(was_lichtSlot);












        //THIS IS THE PART WHERE I NEED HELP!!



        MakeRequest(function(data){
            console.log("asddd");
            speechOutput = "This is a place holder response for the intent named LichtIntent, which includes dialogs. This intent has 2 slots, which are zimmer, and was_licht. Anything else?";


            var speechOutput = data;


            this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, speechOutput);

        });

        console.log("asdww");

        //DOWN TO HERE!!








    },
    'StromIntent': function () {
        //delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slot values
       let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);
        speechOutput = '';
        //any intent slot variables are listed here for convenience

        let geraet_stromSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.geraet_strom.value;
        console.log(geraet_stromSlotRaw);
        let geraet_stromSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.geraet_strom);
        console.log(geraet_stromSlot);
        let wasSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.was.value;
        console.log(wasSlotRaw);
        let wasSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.was);
        console.log(wasSlot);

        //Your custom intent handling goes here
        speechOutput = "This is a place holder response for the intent named StromIntent, which includes dialogs. This intent has 2 slots, which are geraet_strom, and was. Anything else?";
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, speechOutput);
    },
    'FrageIntent': function () {
        //delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slot values
       let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);
        speechOutput = '';
        //any intent slot variables are listed here for convenience

        let geraetSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.geraet.value;
        console.log(geraetSlotRaw);
        let geraetSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.geraet);
        console.log(geraetSlot);
        let was_frageSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.was_frage.value;
        console.log(was_frageSlotRaw);
        let was_frageSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.was_frage);
        console.log(was_frageSlot);

        //Your custom intent handling goes here
        speechOutput = "This is a place holder response for the intent named FrageIntent, which includes dialogs. This intent has 2 slots, which are geraet, and was_frage. Anything else?";
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, speechOutput);
    },
    'TuerIntent': function () {
        //delegate to Alexa to collect all the required slot values
       let filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);
        speechOutput = '';
        //any intent slot variables are listed here for convenience

        let zeitSlotRaw = this.event.request.intent.slots.zeit.value;
        console.log(zeitSlotRaw);
        let zeitSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.zeit);
        console.log(zeitSlot);

        //Your custom intent handling goes here
        speechOutput = "This is a place holder response for the intent named TuerIntent, which includes dialogs. This intent has one slot, which is zeit. Anything else?";
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, speechOutput);
    },  
    'Unhandled': function () {
        speechOutput = "The skill didn't quite understand what you wanted.  Do you want to try something else?";
        this.emit(':ask', speechOutput, speechOutput);
    }
};

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
    //alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    //alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME'; //uncomment this line to save attributes to DB
    alexa.execute();
};

//    END of Intent Handlers {} ========================================================================================
// 3. Helper Function  =================================================================================================










//THESE ARE MY HELPER FUNCTIONS
    function url(){
        console.log("asd");
        return " my server ip";
    }
    function MakeRequest(callback){
        console.log("hallo!");
        request.get(url(), function(error, response, body){

            console.log("****************************************");
            console.log(response);
            console.log("****************************************");

        console.log(error);     
        console.log("****************************************");

        console.log(body);
        console.log("****************************************");

        callback("erfolg!");
    });
    console.log("hffggh");
}

//DOWN TO HERE!!






















function resolveCanonical(slot){
    //this function looks at the entity resolution part of request and returns the slot value if a synonyms is provided
    let canonical;
    try{
        canonical = slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name;
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
        canonical = slot.value;
    };
    return canonical;
};

function delegateSlotCollection(){
  console.log("in delegateSlotCollection");
  console.log("current dialogState: "+this.event.request.dialogState);
    if (this.event.request.dialogState === "STARTED") {
      console.log("in Beginning");
      let updatedIntent= null;
      // updatedIntent=this.event.request.intent;
      //optionally pre-fill slots: update the intent object with slot values for which
      //you have defaults, then return Dialog.Delegate with this updated intent
      // in the updatedIntent property
      //this.emit(":delegate", updatedIntent); //uncomment this is using ASK SDK 1.0.9 or newer

      //this code is necessary if using ASK SDK versions prior to 1.0.9 
      if(this.isOverridden()) {
            return;
        }
        this.handler.response = buildSpeechletResponse({
            sessionAttributes: this.attributes,
            directives: getDialogDirectives('Dialog.Delegate', updatedIntent, null),
            shouldEndSession: false
        });
        this.emit(':responseReady', updatedIntent);

    } else if (this.event.request.dialogState !== "COMPLETED") {
      console.log("in not completed");
      // return a Dialog.Delegate directive with no updatedIntent property.
      //this.emit(":delegate"); //uncomment this is using ASK SDK 1.0.9 or newer

      //this code necessary is using ASK SDK versions prior to 1.0.9
        if(this.isOverridden()) {
            return;
        }
        this.handler.response = buildSpeechletResponse({
            sessionAttributes: this.attributes,
            directives: getDialogDirectives('Dialog.Delegate', null, null),
            shouldEndSession: false
        });
        this.emit(':responseReady');

    } else {
      console.log("in completed");
      console.log("returning: "+ JSON.stringify(this.event.request.intent));
      // Dialog is now complete and all required slots should be filled,
      // so call your normal intent handler.
      return this.event.request.intent;
    }
}


function randomPhrase(array) {
    // the argument is an array [] of words or phrases
    let i = 0;
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    return(array[i]);
}
function isSlotValid(request, slotName){
        let slot = request.intent.slots[slotName];
        //console.log("request = "+JSON.stringify(request)); //uncomment if you want to see the request
        let slotValue;

        //if we have a slot, get the text and store it into speechOutput
        if (slot && slot.value) {
            //we have a value in the slot
            slotValue = slot.value.toLowerCase();
            return slotValue;
        } else {
            //we didn't get a value in the slot.
            return false;
        }
}

//These functions are here to allow dialog directives to work with SDK versions prior to 1.0.9
//will be removed once Lambda templates are updated with the latest SDK

function createSpeechObject(optionsParam) {
    if (optionsParam && optionsParam.type === 'SSML') {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type,
            ssml: optionsParam['speech']
        };
    } else {
        return {
            type: optionsParam.type || 'PlainText',
            text: optionsParam['speech'] || optionsParam
        };
    }
}

function buildSpeechletResponse(options) {
    let alexaResponse = {
        shouldEndSession: options.shouldEndSession
    };

    if (options.output) {
        alexaResponse.outputSpeech = createSpeechObject(options.output);
    }

    if (options.reprompt) {
        alexaResponse.reprompt = {
            outputSpeech: createSpeechObject(options.reprompt)
        };
    }

    if (options.directives) {
        alexaResponse.directives = options.directives;
    }

    if (options.cardTitle && options.cardContent) {
        alexaResponse.card = {
            type: 'Simple',
            title: options.cardTitle,
            content: options.cardContent
        };

        if(options.cardImage && (options.cardImage.smallImageUrl || options.cardImage.largeImageUrl)) {
            alexaResponse.card.type = 'Standard';
            alexaResponse.card['image'] = {};

            delete alexaResponse.card.content;
            alexaResponse.card.text = options.cardContent;

            if(options.cardImage.smallImageUrl) {
                alexaResponse.card.image['smallImageUrl'] = options.cardImage.smallImageUrl;
            }

            if(options.cardImage.largeImageUrl) {
                alexaResponse.card.image['largeImageUrl'] = options.cardImage.largeImageUrl;
            }
        }
    } else if (options.cardType === 'LinkAccount') {
        alexaResponse.card = {
            type: 'LinkAccount'
        };
    } else if (options.cardType === 'AskForPermissionsConsent') {
        alexaResponse.card = {
            type: 'AskForPermissionsConsent',
            permissions: options.permissions
        };
    }

    let returnResult = {
        version: '1.0',
        response: alexaResponse
    };

    if (options.sessionAttributes) {
        returnResult.sessionAttributes = options.sessionAttributes;
    }
    return returnResult;
}

function getDialogDirectives(dialogType, updatedIntent, slotName) {
    let directive = {
        type: dialogType
    };

    if (dialogType === 'Dialog.ElicitSlot') {
        directive.slotToElicit = slotName;
    } else if (dialogType === 'Dialog.ConfirmSlot') {
        directive.slotToConfirm = slotName;
    }

    if (updatedIntent) {
        directive.updatedIntent = updatedIntent;
    }
    return [directive];
}
```

I use the "request" module for my http-request, I think you all know this module.

When I test my function, it gives me NO runtime error!
but the anonymous functions from the MakeRequest call and the request.get call wont execute, and I don't know why.
For Example the console output:

Hallo!,

Asd (very funny.. it gets the params for the request.get.. the bug has to be between the second param(the anon function itself?) in the call and the start of the anon function),

hffggh,

asdww

-the console.logs in the anon. functions doesn't show.

I maybe undestand why the MakeRequest funct. doesn't run -> because the callback from it never came. But why does the request.get not work?? I pasted the necessary parts (the MakeRequest and the helper functions) in a normal node projekt, and it worked!!? -facepalm.... im nearly crying..

My Goal: I want to receive a response from the server.. - thats all. But it just wont go into the function where I can access the response object(s).

(Scroll down to the helper functions)

Please help me out guys, I could really hit my head against the wall.

Reguards

Comment: I can't tell from your question what is your comment, and what is expected or reported input or output. Can you [edit] the question and clarify the exact results you get.

Comment: Where is `MakeRequest` defined?  Also, doesn't `"use strict";` need to be before all other statements?

Comment: I guess its the `MakeRequest(function(data){ ... })` code. By using the `function (data)` instead of the arrow function  `(data) => { ... }` you re-bind the `this` keyword to the new function scope and not the the Alexa emitter and the event drifts into the void (see also: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/44)